# How to send auth_token in Http header

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create rest based webservices, which I want to secure them using spring security Oauth2.

What I found is then, in oauth2 we have to send auth_token in query string.

But my need is to send in header.

I have searched a lot, but I didn't get the answer which I need.

Is there anybody who can help?

Reference link [ http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html
]

Answer (score 0):

You can test sending the access token for example using  [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.example.com
```

With this you should be able to see, if server is working as expected. How to do it in client application depends on the programming language you are using.